# How do I measure pagespeed scores on my pages using datadog? Or rather, is it even possible to keep track of pagespeed scores?

Tags: monitoring, datadog

Work at an org that has datadog for the whole org... however I don't know how to measure my pagespeed scores via datadog... would be nice. Is there a method of doing that?

Tried looking a few places in the platform... I can't even remember how I got to see that pagespeed scores were visible... but don't remember how to get back to it unfortunately

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.